# How can I display result in react using Elasticsearch query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to display result which I get from running the query in react for Elasticsearch but I'm unable to do that. It's giving error but when I am running the same query in a variable it returning the currect result.
Can someone please tell me how to store the result in the "results" array and how to display that in the webpage?

My Code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import client from './Credentials';
import '../App.css';
import DisplayResult from './DisplayResult';
export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {results: []};
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const search_query = event.target.value;

        client.search({
            index: 'tweet',
            type: 'tweet',
            size: 100,
            body: {
                query: {
                    match: {"text": "new"}
                },
            }
        }, function (error, response, status) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                // console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                        console.log(hit._source.text);
                        this.setState(results: hit._source.text)
                    }.bind(this)

                )
            }
        });
    }




    render() {

        return(

            <div>
                <input className={"search-bar"} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                </input>
                <DisplayResult results={this.state.results} />
                {/*<button className={"button"}><Search /></button>*/}

            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

Comment: what does DisplayResult do?

Comment: It just iterates over result to display it: {return (
            <div className="search_results">
                <hr />
                <ul>
                    {results.map(result => {
                        return (
                            <li key={result.source.user_id}>
                                {result._source.text}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>}

Comment: you mentioned it's giving you an error, what error?

Comment: I'm getting this "Line 36:  'results' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: this.setState(results: hit._source.text) is incorrect syntax for setting the state, it should be in object structure: this.setState({ results: hit._source.text }).

Comment: @LefiTarik Now I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Comment: is the binding still in your code ?

Comment: If you mean ".bind(this)" then yes

Answer (score 0):

in your code you're updating the results in the state for each iteration,
try to update the state as below:

```
this.setState({
  results: response.hits.hits.map(hit =>
    ({ text: hit._source.text, userId: hit._source.user_id })
  )
});
```

and simply consume it with a simple map:

```
results.map(result => (
  <li key={result.userId}>{result.text}</li>
));
```

if it doesn't work or still got the error please give me more of your code,
something that i could run ?

**Updated:** 
i think that the elasticsearch client looses the this context somehow, but this was working in my machine, i've used the *async/await* method try it out:

```
export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searched: false,
      results: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = async event => {
    const search_query = event.target.value;
    const response = await client.search({ q: search_query });

    this.setState({
      searched: true,
      results: response.hits.hits.map(item => ({
        userId: item._source.user_id,
        text: item._source.text
      }))
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { searched, results } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className={'search-bar'}
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <DisplayResult searched={searched} results={results} />
        {/*<button className={"button"}><Search /></button>*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the DisplayResult component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const renderResult = results =>
  results.map(result => <li key={result.userId}>{result.text}</li>);

export default class DisplayResult extends Component {
  render() {
    const { searched, results } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="search_results">
        <hr />
        {results.length > 0 ? (
          <ul>{renderResult(results)}</ul>
        ) : searched && (
          <h1>there is no result</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still getting error in setState. How can I share that?

Comment: try this first: onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}

Comment: the problem is the context of 'this' was undefined, so there is a binding problem.

Comment: you will have to run elasticsearch on your local machine

Comment: i could use mock of data.

Comment: Ok, I included the data file with it too "tweet.txt"